# Storing custom user data in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, elasticsearch

I have a question about best practices regarding storing custom user data in mysql.

Let me explain a bit.

Im working on a newsletter system, like Mailchimp etc.

We have a contact (email)
We have contact details (name, lastname, phone, country etc.)

contact details can vary depending on the input fields the user wants the contact to enter in their forms, so no 2 users will save the data the same way, and is fully up to what they name their fields.

Our first approach was to store all "contact details" in JSON into 1 single column. But that proofed to be tough when having to filter, segment and search this data quick.

So my final question, how do you store custom defined data in a MySQL database, so that it can be handled easily, even in lists of 20.000 contacts etc.

Thanks

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. You may want to find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Alright, i thought there would be some cold hard facts about this. Thanks thou

Comment: https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/Relational_Database_Design.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that people are voting to close this as too broad.

The way to structure your data in a relational database is **very** [well defined.](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/)

> Our first approach was to store all "contact details" in JSON into 1 single column

...and that does not conform to the definition. And that is why you had problems managing the data.

Yes, there are times when breaking the rules is a good idea - but you *always* start by following the first rules of normalization and *only* consider denormalizing your database if you have a problem you can't avoid.

Comment: I will try read this Symcbean, thank you for helping. I have just read that article, and i think you misunderstood my question.